# Renamed jobs' workspace wiped out automatically - how to recover

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We renamed a bunch of jobs of those existing jobs.
Those jobs run on slaves.
The jobs are NOT configured for "clean" in their job configurations.
The jobs workspaces are there on the slaves immediately after the jobs completed.
But we noticed the newly renamed jobs' workspaces are wiped out automatically every night.
We believe the renaming jobs is causing a bug in wiping out workspaces.
How do we stop the wiping out ?
We cannot use hudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.disabled=true because there are other jobs (outside of those renamed jobs) that need clean workspaces before executing jobs executing their build steps.

Will hudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.disabled=true stop all jobs' configuration to "clean workspace" if they are configured to do so ?

Thanks